# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'event.target name') when i trying to make a sign up validated form react native

Tags: react-native

undefined is not an object (evaluating 'event.target name') when i trying to make a sign up validated form react native
Here is my code, plzz help thank you so much
here is file doc online https://docs.google.com/document/d/1WeJtSFEV8zCCy5M_N1pN8SQUFMAmsoQ0-r36iDDunkM/edit?usp=sharing
because i cant upload my code not sure why

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, Alert, TouchableOpacity, Button, TextInput, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Images from '../one/Images';
import { hScale, vScale, fScale } from "react-native-scales";
import Styles from '../one/Styles';

export default class App extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {                                                                                      
      input: {},
      errors: {}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  
  handleChange(event) {
    let input = this.state.input;
    input[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
  
    this.setState({
      input
    });
  }
  
  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  
    if(this.validate()){
        console.log(this.state);
  
        let input = {};
        input["username"] = "";
        input["email"] = "";
        input["password"] = "";
        input["confirm_password"] = "";
        this.setState({input:input});
  
        alert('Đã Đăng Ký');
    }
  }
  
  validate(){
      let input = this.state.input;
      let errors = {};
      let isValid = true;
   
      if (!input["username"]) {
        isValid = false;
        errors["username"] = "Xin Nhập Tên Người Dùng.";
      }
  
      if (typeof input["username"] !== "undefined") {
        const re = /^\S*$/;
        if(input["username"].length < 6 || !re.test(input["username"])){
            isValid = false;
            errors["username"] = "Xin Nhập Tên người Dùng Nhỏ Hơn 6 Ký Tự.";
        }
      }
  
      if (!input["email"]) {
        isValid = false;
        errors["email"] = "Xin Nhập Địa Chỉ Email.";
      }
  
      if (typeof input["email"] !== "undefined") {
          
        var pattern = new RegExp(/^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?$)/i);
        if (!pattern.test(input["email"])) {
          isValid = false;
          errors["email"] = "Xin Nhập Địa Chỉ Email Chính Xác.";
        }
      }
  
      if (!input["password"]) {
        isValid = false;
        errors["password"] = "Xin Nhập Mật Khẩu.";
      }
  
      if (!input["confirm_password"]) {
        isValid = false;
        errors["confirm_password"] = "Please enter your confirm password.";
      }
  
      if (typeof input["password"] !== "undefined") {
        if(input["password"].length < 6){
            isValid = false;
            errors["password"] = "Xin Nhập Mật Khẩu Nhất 6 Ký Tự.";
        }
      }
  
      if (typeof input["password"] !== "undefined" && typeof input["confirm_password"] !== "undefined") {
          
        if (input["password"] != input["confirm_password"]) {
          isValid = false;
          errors["password"] = "Mật Khẩu Không Trùng Khớp.";
        }
      }
  
      this.setState({
        errors: errors
      });
  
      return isValid;
  }
 
  render() {
    return (                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
      <View style={Styles.container}>
        <TextInput
          value={this.state.input.username}
          onChangeText={this.handleChange}
          placeholder={'Tên Đăng Nhập'}
          style={Styles.title}
          blurOnSubmit={false}
          returnKeyType="next"
          onSubmitEditing={() => { this.secondTextInput.focus(); }}
          id="username"
        />
         <TextInput
          value={this.state.input.email}
          onChangeText={this.handleChange}
          placeholder={'Email'}
          style={Styles.title}
          onSubmitEditing={() => { this.thirdTextInput.focus(); }}
          ref={(input) => { this.secondTextInput = input; }}
          returnKeyType="next"
          blurOnSubmit={false}
         id="email"          
        />
       <TextInput
          value={this.state.input.password}
          onChangeText={this.handleChange}
          placeholder={'Mật Khẩu'}
          secureTextEntry={true}
          style={Styles.title}
          onSubmitEditing={() => { this.fourTextInput.focus(); }}
          ref={(input) => { this.thirdTextInput = input; }}
          returnKeyType="next"
          blurOnSubmit={false}
          id="password"       
        />
        <TextInput
          value={this.state.input.confirm_password}
          onChangeText={this.handleChange}
          placeholder={'Xác Nhận Mật Khẩu'}
          secureTextEntry={true}
          style={Styles.title}
          ref={(input) => { this.fourTextInput = input; }}
          returnKeyType="go"
          id="confirm_password"
           
        />
          <TouchableOpacity
           onPress={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}
            style={{
              borderRadius: vScale(50),
              backgroundColor: '#0260AF',
              marginTop: vScale(50),
              alignItems: 'center',
              justifyContent: 'center',
              marginLeft: vScale(20),
              marginRight: vScale(20),

            }}>
            <Text style={{
              marginLeft: vScale(20),
              marginRight: vScale(20),
              height: vScale(46),
              fontSize: 20,
              color: '#FFFFFF',
              marginTop: vScale(10),
              fontFamily: 'GoogleSans',
            }}>Đăng Nhập</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  Alert,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Button,
  TextInput,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
} from 'react-native';
import { hScale, vScale, fScale } from "react-native-scales";

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      input: {
        username: null,
        email: null,
        password: null,
        confirm_password: null,
      },
      errors: {
        username: null,
        email: null,
        password: null,
        confirm_password: null,
      },
    };
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    //event.preventDefault();

    if (this.validate()) {
      alert('ok');
      console.log(this.state);

       this.setState((prevState) => {
              let input = Object.assign({}, prevState.input);
              input.username = null;
              input.password = null;
              input.email = null;
              input.confirm_password = null;
              return { input };
       });
         this.setState((prevState) => {
              let errors = Object.assign({}, prevState.errors);
              errors.username = null;
              errors.password = null;
              errors.email = null;
              errors.confirm_password = null;
              return { errors };
       });

      alert('Đã Đăng Ký');
    }
  }

  validate = () =>{
    let input = this.state.input;
    let errors = {};
    let isValid = true;

    if (!input.username) {
      isValid = false;
      this.setState((prevState) => {
        let errors = Object.assign({}, prevState.errors);
        errors.username = 'Xin Nhập Tên Người Dùng.';
        return { errors };
      });
    }

    if (!input.email) {
      isValid = false;
      this.setState((prevState) => {
        let errors = Object.assign({}, prevState.errors);
        errors.email = 'Xin Nhập Địa Chỉ Email';
        return { errors };
      });
    }

    if (!input.password) {
      isValid = false;
      this.setState((prevState) => {
        let errors = Object.assign({}, prevState.errors);
        errors.password = 'Xin Nhập Mật Khẩu.';
        return { errors };
      });
    }

    if (!input.confirm_password) {
      isValid = false;
      this.setState((prevState) => {
        let errors = Object.assign({}, prevState.errors);
        errors.password = 'Please enter your confirm password.';
        return { errors };
      });
    }

    if (input.username) {
      const re = /^\S*$/;
      if (input.username.length < 6 || !re.test(input.username)) {
        isValid = false;
        this.setState((prevState) => {
          let errors = Object.assign({}, prevState.errors);
          errors.username = 'Xin Nhập Tên người Dùng Nhỏ Hơn 6 Ký Tự.';
          return { errors };
        });
      }
    }

    if (input.email) {
      let pattern = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
      if (!pattern.test(input.email)) {
        isValid = false;
        this.setState((prevState) => {
          let errors = Object.assign({}, prevState.errors);
          errors.email = 'Xin Nhập Địa Chỉ Email Chính Xác.';
          return { errors };
        });
      }
    }

    if (input.password) {
      if (input.password.length < 6) {
        isValid = false;

        this.setState((prevState) => {
          let errors = Object.assign({}, prevState.errors);
          errors.password = 'Xin Nhập Mật Khẩu Nhất 6 Ký Tự.';
          return { errors };
        });
      }
    }

    if (input.password && input.confirm_password) {
      if (input.password != input.confirm_password) {
        isValid = false;
        this.setState((prevState) => {
          let errors = Object.assign({}, prevState.errors);
          errors.confirm_password = 'Mật Khẩu Không Trùng Khớp.';
          return { errors };
        });
      }
    }

    return isValid;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex:1, justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'}}>
        <View style={{padding:5}}>
        <TextInput
          value={this.state.input.username}
          onChangeText={(text) => {
            this.setState((prevState) => {
              let input = Object.assign({}, prevState.input);
              input.username = text;
              return { input };
            });
          }}

          placeholder={'Tên Đăng Nhập'}
          blurOnSubmit={false}
          returnKeyType="next"
          onSubmitEditing={() => {
            this.secondTextInput.focus();
          }}
          id="username"
          name="username"
        />{this.state.errors.username? <Text>{this.state.errors.username}</Text>:null}
        <TextInput
          value={this.state.input.email}

          onChangeText={(text) => {
             this.setState((prevState) => {
              let input = Object.assign({}, prevState.input);
              input.email = text;
              return { input };
            });
          }}
          placeholder={'Email'}
          onSubmitEditing={() => {
            this.thirdTextInput.focus();
          }}
          ref={(input) => {
            this.secondTextInput = input;
          }}
          returnKeyType="next"
          blurOnSubmit={false}
          id="email"
        />{this.state.errors.email? <Text>{this.state.errors.email}</Text>:null}
        <TextInput
          value={this.state.input.password}

          onChangeText={(text) => {
             this.setState((prevState) => {
              let input = Object.assign({}, prevState.input);
              input.password = text;
              return { input };
            });
          }}
          placeholder={'Mật Khẩu'}
          secureTextEntry={true}
          onSubmitEditing={() => {
            this.fourTextInput.focus();
          }}
          ref={(input) => {
            this.thirdTextInput = input;
          }}
          returnKeyType="next"
          blurOnSubmit={false}
          id="password"
        />{this.state.errors.password? <Text>{this.state.errors.password}</Text>:null}
        <TextInput
          value={this.state.input.confirm_password}

          onChangeText={(text) => {
            this.setState((prevState) => {
              let input = Object.assign({}, prevState.input);
              input.confirm_password = text;
              return { input };
            });
          }}
          placeholder={'Xác Nhận Mật Khẩu'}
          secureTextEntry={true}
          ref={(input) => {
            this.fourTextInput = input;
          }}
          onSubmitEditing={e=>{this.validate()}}
          returnKeyType="go"
          id="confirm_password"
        />{this.state.errors.confirm_password? <Text>{this.state.errors.confirm_password}</Text>:null}
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={(e)=>{this.handleSubmit(e);}}
          style={{
            borderRadius: vScale(50),
            backgroundColor: '#0260AF',
            marginTop: vScale(50),
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            marginLeft: vScale(20),
            marginRight: vScale(20),
          }}>
          <Text
            style={{
              marginLeft: vScale(20),
              marginRight: vScale(20),
              height: vScale(46),
              fontSize: 20,
              color: '#FFFFFF',
              marginTop: vScale(10),
              fontFamily: 'GoogleSans',
            }}>
            Đăng Nhập
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  Alert,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Button,
  TextInput,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
} from 'react-native';
import Images from '../one/Images';
import { hScale, vScale, fScale } from "react-native-scales";
import Styles from '../one/Styles';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      input: {
        username: null,
        email: null,
        password: null,
        confirm_password: null,
      },
      errors: {
        username: null,
        email: null,
        password: null,
        confirm_password: null,
      },
    };
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (this.validate()) {
      alert('ok');
      console.log(this.state);

       this.setState((prevState) => {
              let input = Object.assign({}, prevState.input);
              input.username = null;
              input.password = null;
              input.email = null;
              input.confirm_password = null;
              return { input };
       });

      alert('Đã Đăng Ký');
    }
  }

  validate() {
    let input = this.state.input;
    let errors = {};
    let isValid = true;

    if (!input.username) {
      isValid = false;
      this.setState((prevState) => {
        let errors = Object.assign({}, prevState.errors);
        errors.username = 'Xin Nhập Tên Người Dùng.';
        return { errors };
      });
    }

    if (!input.email) {
      isValid = false;
      this.setState((prevState) => {
        let errors = Object.assign({}, prevState.errors);
        errors.email = 'Xin Nhập Địa Chỉ Email';
        return { errors };
      });
    }

    if (!input.password) {
      isValid = false;
      this.setState((prevState) => {
        let errors = Object.assign({}, prevState.errors);
        errors.password = 'Xin Nhập Mật Khẩu.';
        return { errors };
      });
    }

    if (!input.confirm_password) {
      isValid = false;
      this.setState((prevState) => {
        let errors = Object.assign({}, prevState.errors);
        errors.password = 'Please enter your confirm password.';
        return { errors };
      });
    }

    if (input.username) {
      const re = /^\S*$/;
      if (input.username.length < 6 || !re.test(input.username)) {
        isValid = false;
        this.setState((prevState) => {
          let errors = Object.assign({}, prevState.errors);
          errors.username = 'Xin Nhập Tên người Dùng Nhỏ Hơn 6 Ký Tự.';
          return { errors };
        });
      }
    }

    if (input.email) {
      let pattern = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
      if (!pattern.test(input.email)) {
        isValid = false;
        this.setState((prevState) => {
          let errors = Object.assign({}, prevState.errors);
          errors.email = 'Xin Nhập Địa Chỉ Email Chính Xác.';
          return { errors };
        });
      }
    }

    if (input.password) {
      if (input.password.length < 6) {
        isValid = false;

        this.setState((prevState) => {
          let errors = Object.assign({}, prevState.errors);
          errors.password = 'Xin Nhập Mật Khẩu Nhất 6 Ký Tự.';
          return { errors };
        });
      }
    }

    if (input.password && input.confirm_password) {
      if (input.password != input.confirm_password) {
        isValid = false;
        this.setState((prevState) => {
          let errors = Object.assign({}, prevState.errors);
          errors.confirm_password = 'Mật Khẩu Không Trùng Khớp.';
          return { errors };
        });
      }
    }

    return isValid;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={Styles.container}>
        <TextInput
          value={this.state.input.username}
          onChangeText={(text) => {
            this.setState((prevState) => {
              let input = Object.assign({}, prevState.input);
              input.username = text;
              return { input };
            });
          }}
style={Styles.title}
          placeholder={'Tên Đăng Nhập'}
          blurOnSubmit={false}
          returnKeyType="next"
          onSubmitEditing={() => {
            this.secondTextInput.focus();
          }}
          id="username"
          name="username"
        />
        <TextInput
          value={this.state.input.email}
style={Styles.title}
          onChangeText={(text) => {
             this.setState((prevState) => {
              let input = Object.assign({}, prevState.input);
              input.email = text;
              return { input };
            });
          }}
          placeholder={'Email'}
          onSubmitEditing={() => {
            this.thirdTextInput.focus();
          }}
          ref={(input) => {
            this.secondTextInput = input;
          }}
          returnKeyType="next"
          blurOnSubmit={false}
          id="email"
        />
        <TextInput
          value={this.state.input.password}
style={Styles.title}
          onChangeText={(text) => {
             this.setState((prevState) => {
              let input = Object.assign({}, prevState.input);
              input.password = text;
              return { input };
            });
          }}
          placeholder={'Mật Khẩu'}
          secureTextEntry={true}
          onSubmitEditing={() => {
            this.fourTextInput.focus();
          }}
          ref={(input) => {
            this.thirdTextInput = input;
          }}
          returnKeyType="next"
          blurOnSubmit={false}
          id="password"
        />
        <TextInput
          value={this.state.input.confirm_password}
style={Styles.title}
          onChangeText={(text) => {
            this.setState((prevState) => {
              let input = Object.assign({}, prevState.input);
              input.confirm_password = text;
              return { input };
            });
          }}
          placeholder={'Xác Nhận Mật Khẩu'}
          secureTextEntry={true}
          ref={(input) => {
            this.fourTextInput = input;
          }}
          returnKeyType="go"
          id="confirm_password"
        />
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}
          style={{
            borderRadius: vScale(50),
            backgroundColor: '#0260AF',
            marginTop: vScale(50),
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            marginLeft: vScale(20),
            marginRight: vScale(20),
          }}>
          <Text
            style={{
              marginLeft: vScale(20),
              marginRight: vScale(20),
              height: vScale(46),
              fontSize: 20,
              color: '#FFFFFF',
              marginTop: vScale(10),
              fontFamily: 'GoogleSans',
            }}>
            Đăng Nhập
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: hmm it no long show up erro but it also not show up the alert when i try to submit

Comment: also other function like validate pass word and check email format not work anymore too hmm plz help

Comment: replace email pattern with this /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/

Answer (score 1):

```
 <TextInput
          value={this.state.input.username}
          onChangeText={(text) => {
            this.setState((prevState) => {
              let input = Object.assign({}, prevState.input);
              input.username = text;
              return { input };
            });
          }}
style={Styles.title}
          placeholder={'Tên Đăng Nhập'}
          blurOnSubmit={false}
          returnKeyType="next"
          onSubmitEditing={() => {
            this.secondTextInput.focus();
          }}
          id="username"
          name="username"
        /> {this.state.errors.username? <Text>{this.state.errors.username}</Text>:null}
```

same for all

Comment: i use this and it show up new erro" text string must render within a text component

Comment: the full code show no erro but those validate format email check password and submit function still not working

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the "name" prop to your TextInput components, like this:

```
<TextInput
    value={this.state.input.username}
    onChangeText={this.handleChange}
    placeholder={'Tên Đăng Nhập'}
    style={Styles.title}
    blurOnSubmit={false}
    returnKeyType="next"
    onSubmitEditing={() => { this.secondTextInput.focus(); }}
    id="username"
    name="username"
/>
```

Do that for the rest of the TextInputs components.

Also, fix your "handleChange" method, like this:

```
handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
        input: {
           [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: may i ask what line i need to pass ' name'?

Comment: hmm with email password and confirm_password what prop i need to pass? i tried with all name prop and it still erro...i doing something wrong?

Comment: You have to pass the "name" prop, too. But I realized that your "handleChange" method is not correct. Try using this code.

Comment: well i do everything as u say but still same erro hmm.. maybe other methods are erro too? can u check for me plz

Answer (score 0):

```
handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (this.validate()) {
      alert('ok');
      console.log(this.state);

       this.setState((prevState) => {
              let input = Object.assign({}, prevState.input);
              input.username = null;
              input.password = null;
              input.email = null;
              input.confirm_password = null;
              return { input };
       });
         this.setState((prevState) => {
              let errors = Object.assign({}, prevState.errors);
              errors.username = null;
              errors.password = null;
              errors.email = null;
              errors.confirm_password = null;
              return { errors };
       });

      alert('Đã Đăng Ký');
    }
  }

  validate() {
    let input = this.state.input;
    let errors = {};
    let isValid = true;

    if (!input.username) {
      isValid = false;
      this.setState((prevState) => {
        let errors = Object.assign({}, prevState.errors);
        errors.username = 'Xin Nhập Tên Người Dùng.';
        return { errors };
      });
    }

    if (!input.email) {
      isValid = false;
      this.setState((prevState) => {
        let errors = Object.assign({}, prevState.errors);
        errors.email = 'Xin Nhập Địa Chỉ Email';
        return { errors };
      });
    }

    if (!input.password) {
      isValid = false;
      this.setState((prevState) => {
        let errors = Object.assign({}, prevState.errors);
        errors.password = 'Xin Nhập Mật Khẩu.';
        return { errors };
      });
    }

    if (!input.confirm_password) {
      isValid = false;
      this.setState((prevState) => {
        let errors = Object.assign({}, prevState.errors);
        errors.password = 'Please enter your confirm password.';
        return { errors };
      });
    }

    if (input.username) {
      const re = /^\S*$/;
      if (input.username.length < 6 || !re.test(input.username)) {
        isValid = false;
        this.setState((prevState) => {
          let errors = Object.assign({}, prevState.errors);
          errors.username = 'Xin Nhập Tên người Dùng Nhỏ Hơn 6 Ký Tự.';
          return { errors };
        });
      }
    }

    if (input.email) {
      let pattern = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
      if (!pattern.test(input.email)) {
        isValid = false;
        this.setState((prevState) => {
          let errors = Object.assign({}, prevState.errors);
          errors.email = 'Xin Nhập Địa Chỉ Email Chính Xác.';
          return { errors };
        });
      }
    }

    if (input.password) {
      if (input.password.length < 6) {
        isValid = false;

        this.setState((prevState) => {
          let errors = Object.assign({}, prevState.errors);
          errors.password = 'Xin Nhập Mật Khẩu Nhất 6 Ký Tự.';
          return { errors };
        });
      }
    }

    if (input.password && input.confirm_password) {
      if (input.password != input.confirm_password) {
        isValid = false;
        this.setState((prevState) => {
          let errors = Object.assign({}, prevState.errors);
          errors.confirm_password = 'Mật Khẩu Không Trùng Khớp.';
          return { errors };
        });
      }
    }

    return isValid;
  }
```

Updated your code with this.

Comment: it still not work my submit button do nothing and other validate too hmm wtf is wrong with my app lol

Comment: onPress={this.handleSubmit} try this

Comment: onPress={(e)=>{this.handleSubmit(e)}}

Comment: remove this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);

Comment: //event.preventDefault();

Comment: onPress={()=>{alert('test');}}

Comment: submit function can work now but it show up with ur test alert  and no validate seem u checking code again?

Comment: check this snack, https://snack.expo.io/@vijeeshin/talking-donut

Comment: thank god ur snack work like a charm thank you so much btw can u copy and paste ur snack to another answer so i can in it to the answer done?

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  Alert,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Button,
  TextInput,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
} from 'react-native';
import { hScale, vScale, fScale } from "react-native-scales";

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      input: {
        username: null,
        email: null,
        password: null,
        confirm_password: null,
      },
      errors: {
        username: null,
        email: null,
        password: null,
        confirm_password: null,
      },
    };
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    //event.preventDefault();

    if (this.validate()) {
      alert('ok');
      console.log(this.state);

       this.setState((prevState) => {
              let input = Object.assign({}, prevState.input);
              input.username = null;
              input.password = null;
              input.email = null;
              input.confirm_password = null;
              return { input };
       });
         this.setState((prevState) => {
              let errors = Object.assign({}, prevState.errors);
              errors.username = null;
              errors.password = null;
              errors.email = null;
              errors.confirm_password = null;
              return { errors };
       });

      alert('Đã Đăng Ký');
    }
  }

  validate = () =>{
    let input = this.state.input;
    let errors = {};
    let isValid = true;

    if (!input.username) {
      isValid = false;
      this.setState((prevState) => {
        let errors = Object.assign({}, prevState.errors);
        errors.username = 'Xin Nhập Tên Người Dùng.';
        return { errors };
      });
    }

    if (!input.email) {
      isValid = false;
      this.setState((prevState) => {
        let errors = Object.assign({}, prevState.errors);
        errors.email = 'Xin Nhập Địa Chỉ Email';
        return { errors };
      });
    }

    if (!input.password) {
      isValid = false;
      this.setState((prevState) => {
        let errors = Object.assign({}, prevState.errors);
        errors.password = 'Xin Nhập Mật Khẩu.';
        return { errors };
      });
    }

    if (!input.confirm_password) {
      isValid = false;
      this.setState((prevState) => {
        let errors = Object.assign({}, prevState.errors);
        errors.password = 'Please enter your confirm password.';
        return { errors };
      });
    }

    if (input.username) {
      const re = /^\S*$/;
      if (input.username.length < 6 || !re.test(input.username)) {
        isValid = false;
        this.setState((prevState) => {
          let errors = Object.assign({}, prevState.errors);
          errors.username = 'Xin Nhập Tên người Dùng Nhỏ Hơn 6 Ký Tự.';
          return { errors };
        });
      }
    }

    if (input.email) {
      let pattern = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
      if (!pattern.test(input.email)) {
        isValid = false;
        this.setState((prevState) => {
          let errors = Object.assign({}, prevState.errors);
          errors.email = 'Xin Nhập Địa Chỉ Email Chính Xác.';
          return { errors };
        });
      }
    }

    if (input.password) {
      if (input.password.length < 6) {
        isValid = false;

        this.setState((prevState) => {
          let errors = Object.assign({}, prevState.errors);
          errors.password = 'Xin Nhập Mật Khẩu Nhất 6 Ký Tự.';
          return { errors };
        });
      }
    }

    if (input.password && input.confirm_password) {
      if (input.password != input.confirm_password) {
        isValid = false;
        this.setState((prevState) => {
          let errors = Object.assign({}, prevState.errors);
          errors.confirm_password = 'Mật Khẩu Không Trùng Khớp.';
          return { errors };
        });
      }
    }

    return isValid;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex:1}}>
        <TextInput
          value={this.state.input.username}
          onChangeText={(text) => {
            this.setState((prevState) => {
              let input = Object.assign({}, prevState.input);
              input.username = text;
              return { input };
            });
          }}

          placeholder={'Tên Đăng Nhập'}
          blurOnSubmit={false}
          returnKeyType="next"
          onSubmitEditing={() => {
            this.secondTextInput.focus();
          }}
          id="username"
          name="username"
        />{this.state.errors.username? <Text>{this.state.errors.username}</Text>:null}
        <TextInput
          value={this.state.input.email}

          onChangeText={(text) => {
             this.setState((prevState) => {
              let input = Object.assign({}, prevState.input);
              input.email = text;
              return { input };
            });
          }}
          placeholder={'Email'}
          onSubmitEditing={() => {
            this.thirdTextInput.focus();
          }}
          ref={(input) => {
            this.secondTextInput = input;
          }}
          returnKeyType="next"
          blurOnSubmit={false}
          id="email"
        />{this.state.errors.email? <Text>{this.state.errors.email}</Text>:null}
        <TextInput
          value={this.state.input.password}

          onChangeText={(text) => {
             this.setState((prevState) => {
              let input = Object.assign({}, prevState.input);
              input.password = text;
              return { input };
            });
          }}
          placeholder={'Mật Khẩu'}
          secureTextEntry={true}
          onSubmitEditing={() => {
            this.fourTextInput.focus();
          }}
          ref={(input) => {
            this.thirdTextInput = input;
          }}
          returnKeyType="next"
          blurOnSubmit={false}
          id="password"
        />{this.state.errors.password? <Text>{this.state.errors.password}</Text>:null}
        <TextInput
          value={this.state.input.confirm_password}

          onChangeText={(text) => {
            this.setState((prevState) => {
              let input = Object.assign({}, prevState.input);
              input.confirm_password = text;
              return { input };
            });
          }}
          placeholder={'Xác Nhận Mật Khẩu'}
          secureTextEntry={true}
          ref={(input) => {
            this.fourTextInput = input;
          }}
          returnKeyType="go"
          id="confirm_password"
        />{this.state.errors.confirm_password? <Text>{this.state.errors.confirm_password}</Text>:null}
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={(e)=>{this.handleSubmit(e);}}
          style={{
            borderRadius: vScale(50),
            backgroundColor: '#0260AF',
            marginTop: vScale(50),
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            marginLeft: vScale(20),
            marginRight: vScale(20),
          }}>
          <Text
            style={{
              marginLeft: vScale(20),
              marginRight: vScale(20),
              height: vScale(46),
              fontSize: 20,
              color: '#FFFFFF',
              marginTop: vScale(10),
              fontFamily: 'GoogleSans',
            }}>
            Đăng Nhập
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: ty this is the answer i looking for but i have 2 things want to ask before done this question :C first is how i can make the returnkey become a button when use it in the "confirm_password" and second is how i put my screen to center like in a real phone sign up screen like alway in center screen